# Rendering a skybox with opengl es from one GL_TEXTURE_EXTERNAL_OES texture

Tags: android, opengl-es, skybox

We are trying to render a skybox / cubemap on Android from a single texture (see the image, each face of the cube is one color), but we are seeing strong seams on most of the edges.

3x2 texture
[image: 3x2 texture]

We have set GL_TEXTURE_WRAP_S & GL_TEXTURE_WRAP_T to GL_CLAMP_TO_EDGE, which removes seams from certain edges, but this has no effect on edges inside the texture.

We initially thought this was only interpolation artifacts, as a result of linear interpolation across these edges, but we still see 1-2px sharp seams when setting `GL_TEXTURE_MAG_FILTER` and `GL_TEXTURE_MIN_FILTER` to `GL_NEAREST`. See examples with linear and with nearest neighbour.

Cube's corner with `GLES30.GL_LINEAR` and `GLES30.GL_NEAREST`
[image: Cube's corner with GLES30.GL_LINEAR and GLES30.GL_NEAREST]

We are reading the texture from an Android SurfaceTexture, so the input texture must be `GL_TEXTURE_EXTERNAL_OES`.
We know this problem should be solvable by using a native `GL_TEXTURE_CUBE_MAP` along with `glEnable(GL_TEXTURE_CUBE_MAP_SEAMLESS)`, but this is not supported for `GL_TEXTURE_EXTERNAL_OES`.

Does anybody have an idea for us on how to solve this? Is it possible to set filtering-restrictions in the shader code?
Is a two-pass rendering with an off-screen framebuffer that we could use to transform the `GL_TEXTURE_EXTERNAL_OES` into a regular 2D texture (and bind that to a cube map), a good solution to attempt?

Comment: Have you tried to use higher precision for texture coordinates?

Comment: Thanks a lot! Increasing the precision from mediump to highp on the texture coordinates made the mapping of the texture to the skybox sides much better! We no longer get the blue strip of pixels between the green and yellow sides as in the picture above. Any idea if it's possible to somehow get rid of the seams along the edges? In a real skybox they are very much visible.

Comment: Glad that helped. You could try to get rid of seams on edges using antialiasing.

Comment: Oh wait, I misread the part about seams. Not sure how to fix that.